# How to wait for completion handler to finish? Dispatch.group?

Tags: swift, dispatch-async

I need help altering my code so that it waits for the completion handler to fire, before looping.

**Problem**

I am trying to run the following block of code:

```
let sourceCodes:[String] = self.makeCodeArray(codeString: (self.sourceDict?["Code"]!)!)

print("A")
for i in 0..<sourceCodes.count
{
    print("B")
    getRealtimeData(stopCode: sourceCodes[i], completion:
    {
        (realtimeSourceResult) in

        print("C")
        self.overallSourceResult.append(realtimeSourceResult)

        if i == sourceCodes.count - 1
        {
            print("D")
        }
        else
        {
            print("K")
        }
    })
}
```

so that the output is:

```
A
B
C
K
B
C
K
B
C    (BCK repeating until the last iteration)
K
...
B
C
D
```

However, currently the code is executing in the following order: *A B B B B ... C K C K C K C D*

How would I change my code so that it executes in the desired manner? I have tried using Dispatch.group but I cannot seem to get that working either.

**Here is my attempted solution using Dispatch.group**

```
let sourceCodes:[String] = self.makeCodeArray(codeString: (self.sourceDict?["Code"]!)!)
let group = DispatchGroup()

print("A")
for i in 0..<sourceCodes.count
{
    group.enter()

    print("B")
    getRealtimeData(stopCode: sourceCodes[i], completion:
    {
        (realtimeSourceResult) in

        print("C")
        self.overallSourceResult.append(realtimeSourceResult)

        if i == sourceCodes.count - 1
        {
            print("D")
        }
        else
        {
            group.leave()
            print("K")
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `group.wait()`. And you need to move your `group.leave()` so it always called. `leave` must be called for each `enter` or the `wait` will never stop waiting.

```
print("A")
for i in 0..<sourceCodes.count
{
    group.enter()

    print("B")
    getRealtimeData(stopCode: sourceCodes[i], completion:
    {
        (realtimeSourceResult) in

        print("C")
        self.overallSourceResult.append(realtimeSourceResult)

        if i == sourceCodes.count - 1
        {
            print("D")
        }
        else
        {
            print("K")
        }

        group.leave() // always call this
    })

    group.wait() // don't iterate until the completion handler is done
}
```